# Make a logout button in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core-mvc

I am new to ASP.NET Core and I have made a login page with simple authentication via a session. I am trying to make a button that will log you out, but I cannot figure out how to do it. This is what Ive come up with:

This is my controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
        IConfiguration _Configuration;
        SecurityService _securityService;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger,
            IConfiguration configuration,
            SecurityService securityService)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _Configuration = configuration;
            _securityService = securityService;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var loggedIn = HttpContext.Session.GetString("SessionUser");
            if(loggedIn == "admin")
            {
                return View();
            }
            else
            {
                return View("Login");
            }
        }

        public IActionResult Login(UserModel user)
        {
            Boolean success = _securityService.Authenticate(user, _Configuration);
            

            if (success)
            {
                HttpContext.Session.SetString("SessionUser", user.Username);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                return View("Login");
            }
        }

        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }
```

Here is my SecurityDAO where I look for if the user exists in the database:

```
public class SecurityDAO
    {
        internal bool FindByUser(UserModel user, IConfiguration Configuration)
        {
            string connectionString = Configuration["ConnectionStrings:Database"];
            bool success = false;

            string queryString = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = @username AND password = @password";

            using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(queryString, connection);

                command.Parameters.Add("@username", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = user.Username;
                command.Parameters.Add("@password", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = user.Password;

                try
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        success = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        success = false;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
            return success;
        }
    }
```

Here is my SecurityService:

```
public class SecurityService
    {
        SecurityDAO daoService = new SecurityDAO();

        public bool Authenticate(UserModel user, IConfiguration Configuration)
        {
            return daoService.FindByUser(user, Configuration);
        }
    }
```

Thanks beforehand!
Best regards Max

Comment: have you considered using a `SignInManager<TUser>` to authenticate? You would then just use the SignInManager.SignOutAsync() method to within the appropriate action method within the controller

Comment: How do you mean?

Comment: I mean, have you considered using MS Identity as your authorization service rather than creating your own? MS Identity has many out-of-the-box solutions to do what you're after such as https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.signinmanager-1?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: I tried using it first, but I am currently working on a project that needs so mych less than what identity has, maybe I got it wrong, but I only want my users to be able to sing in, I am going to create the accounts backend is the idea. I only want about 2 accounts, one admin and one user. So I took some time and tried to figure out a small simple one myself.

Comment: I created a simple Logout method or IActionResult in the controller, but how do I call it with the button?

Comment: a button can call through the `asp-action` tag. `<a class="btn" asp-action="Logout" asp-controller="Home">Logout</a>`. You'll need a way to only have this button populate if the user is logged in and this is where Identity can help. E.g., `@if (User?.Identity.IsAuthenticated ?? false)` to determine whether or not to show the Logout button. You may instead need to pass a model that contains your "SessionUser" string, perhaps hiding the Logout button if it is null

Comment: It worked thank you! I am new to stack overflow, how do I add a comment as an answer to my question?

Comment: I'm not sure that you can. I've added an answer below to the same effect. Glad you've got it working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an anchor element to your View and use an `asp-action` tag to call the appropriate action method in your controller:

`<a class="btn" asp-action="Logout" asp-controller="Home">Logout</a>`

If you want to hide this button when a user is logged in you can pass a model string to the View within your controller and determine whether to show the button using your `SessionUser` data

```
@if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.SessionUser))
{
    <a class="btn" asp-action="Logout" asp-controller="Home">Logout</a>
}
```